# Weird startup error in intelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've recently refactored my src directory in my IntelliJ Android project now, when I run my App on the device, I'm getting this weird error. [image]

I've marked the confusing part. Why is there a second package? How do I remove it again. Also, when I then run the app manually, i runs fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has always been there. I mean, if you see a second package name it is not an error. You could have an application whose package id is `the.package` but the main activity could be in another package (e.g. `com.something.else.MainActivity`). In that case you will see something like:

```
Launching application: the.package/com.something.else.MainActivity.
```

What I would take a look at is the `Run/Debug configurations` which sometimes get corrupted after changing the project structure.